# For Loop with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with some code with I can't get to work,
I have to make code so that it prints;

```
Country    Capital
France     Paris 
Uk         London
Belgium    Brussels
etc..
```

This is what I have wrote so far..

```
Country = ["France","UK","Belgium","Spain"]
Capital = ["Paris","London","Brussels","Madrid"]
print("\n\t Country \t Capital")
for country in Country:
  print("\t",country)
for capital in Capital:
  print("\t",capital)
```

but it prints ;

```
 Country     Capital
 France
 UK
 Belgium
 Spain
 Paris
 London
 Brussels
 Madrid
```

i cant seem to get the capitals to be under the capital section. please help, thanks

Comment: I assume you mean `Belgium\tBrussels` in your expected output?

Comment: I bet `zip` would be useful here.

Comment: Try to use `zip`. You should have only one loop

Comment: BTW, using `\t` like that won't align the columns properly. But you can do, eg `for country, capital in zip(Country, Capital): print("{:7} {}".format(country, capital))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using two separate loops to print, so they come one after the other, you'll want one loop, like this:

```
Country = ["France","UK","Belgium","Spain"]
Capital = ["Paris","London","Brussels","Madrid"]
print("\n\t Country \t Capital")
for i in range(len(Country)):
  print("\t",Country[i], "\t", Capital[i], "\n")
```

That way, you'll have tab-separated columns instead of all the countries, then all the capitals.

Comment: Note that your print syntax inside the for-loop only works in Python 3. To keep it compatible with both Python 2 and 3, I'd recommend changing the loop print statement to this:

`print("\t%s\t%s" % (Country[i], Capital[i]))`

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri, no, it works in Python 2 as well, just prints a tuple.

Comment: @ForceBru, But printing a tuple isn't the intended output format specified by OP: the output is supposed to be tab-delimited country-capital pairs

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri The `print` function is available in Python 2.6+ via `from __future__ import print_function`. You really shouldn't use the `print` statement in new code these days.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I agree, but this import was not included in the solution. It should at least be mentioned for it to be complete

Comment: @NiemaMoshiri The OP has tagged the question Python 3, so there's no need to make a solution that also works on Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a one-liner:

```
print("\n".join("\t".join(t) for t in zip(Country, Capital)))
```

output:

```
France  Paris
UK      London
Belgium Brussels
Spain   Madrid
```

Comment: whoever downvoted, it was simply because I mis-copied from the terminl, the code works fine...

Comment: Yeah, downvote seems overzealous, I was about to add this to my answer if Joe didn't undelete.  `zip` is a great (probably the intended) solution to this.

Comment: I downvoted it because you're building a list of `None`s for no reason by using a list comprehension.  One liners are all well and good, but this should be a regular `for` loop

Comment: There's also a superfluous parenthesis after the call to `zip`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Would the current version be better?

Comment: How about this: `sum(map(bool, map(print, map('\t'.join, zip(Country, Capital)))))`? :D

Comment: @ForceBru Very cool! **:)**